# Change model (@ModelAttribute) depending on a request parameter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model, modelattribute

help me please. 
I have the code of controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showOrders(@RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) String status, Model model) {
    if(status != null) {
        Order.Status orderStatus = Order.Status.valueOf(status);
        if (orderStatus != null) model.addAttribute("currentStatus", orderStatus);
    }

    return "admin/orders";
}

@ModelAttribute("currentStatus")
public Order.Status populateCurrentStatus() {
    return Order.Status.PAYMENT;
}

@ModelAttribute("orders")
public List<Order> populateOrders(@ModelAttribute("currentStatus") Order.Status status) {
    return orderBo.getByStatus(status);
}
```

I want the default `currentStatus` to be equal to `Order.Status.PAYMENT`, but if the controller receives a GET request with the argument `status` (on method `showOrders`), then replace `currentStatus` in the model to the `status` transmitted in the request.
And the `populateOrders` should return a different list of orders, in accordance with the new status. But unfortunately, this is not happening. Method `populateOrders` always gets `currentStatus` equal `Order.Status.PAYMENT` and it never changes.

Comment: Yes because that's happening in `showOrders()`. When request goes to that controller method with `@ModelAttribute` executes first and than the mapper. Hence `currentStatus` is overwriiten for a GET request.

Comment: @DarshanLila What the solution to my problem?

Comment: use different attribute name for `currentStatus` in your get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `@RequestParam` to your `@ModelAttribute` definition in order to populate `@ModelAttribute` differently, depending on a request parameter.

This should work:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showOrders() {
    //no need to manually modify currentStatus in the model anymore
    return "admin/orders";
}

@ModelAttribute("currentStatus")
public Order.Status populateCurrentStatus(@RequestParam(value = "status", defaultValue = "PAYMENT") String status) {    
    return Order.Status.valueOf(status);
}

@ModelAttribute("orders")
public List<Order> populateOrders(@ModelAttribute("currentStatus") Order.Status status) {
    return orderBo.getByStatus(status);
}
```

**Personal note:**

I personally dislike Spring's `@ModelAttribute`  system for defining default model attributes, especially in case of more complex models or in more complex controllers. It becomes hard to maintain because it's hard to control what exactly goes into the model (for example, for some requests, maybe you don't want the whole model populated, e.g. you only need currentStatus but not the list of orders. I prefer populating the model manually (`Model.addAttribute(...)`) - it's not much extra work and everything is explicit and easy to debug if a problem pops out later on.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is very simple and ingenious! And thank you warned about the @ModelAttribute!